# Reading messages from oracle queue using spring boot and apache camel

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, apache-camel

I need help with Java, Spring Boot, Apache Camel and Oracle Queue.

Currently I only have a queue with messages in Oracle and I am consuming the messages and sending each message to a function called "processMessage" as shown in the following code:

```
from("oracleQueue:queue:" + queueName).process(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        }
    }).bean(camelBean, "procesMessage").to("log:foo");
```

But, what I have to do is that if one of the read messages has an error and is sent to the exception queue, I need to stop reading the messages from the "main queue", and in case the "exception queue" is empty, I can re-read the messages in the "main queue".

Any idea how to check every moment if the "exception queue" has messages (or not) and how to stop and start the reading of messages from the "main queue" depending if the "exception queue" has messages or not?

Thank you.

Comment: What would be the benefit of having two queues? If you're going to stop consuming messages from the "main" queue if there are messages on the "exception" queue, then essentially you have one logical queue that you essentially retry forever.

Comment: yes, I thought the same, but the client wants each message to have a maximum of 15 retries and if one of the messages exceeds the maximum number of retries, it should be sent to the exception queue.

Comment: But then your logic says that you'll continue to try that message at the exclusion of the others. There will only ever be one message on the exception queue. 

It sounds like the client hasn't fully explored their options. One option might be to send some kind of alert if the message has been retried more than 15 times. It could still sit at the front of the queue and continue to be retried until the error condition has cleared. But overall, this sounds like a bad idea architecturally.